# Passing variables within variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function which looks like this (basically, it's simplified):

```
function getPage(targetURL, targetID, dataMethod, dataStream) {
  $.ajax({
    type: dataMethod,
    data: { dataStream },
    url: '../' + targetURL,
    success:
        function(server_response)   { 
            $('#' + targetID).html(server_response).show();
        }
    });
  return false;
}
```

I then want to call the function like this:

```
onclick="getPage('myPage.php', 'content', 'GET', 'someAction: add');"
```

And that is very good... But right now function thinks add is a variable... But in some cases, I need to declare someAction with a value, from within the onClick, like this:

```
onclick="getPage('myPage.php', 'content', 'GET', 'someAction: "add"');"
```

However, that is ofcourse not working... Neither does ofcourse:

```
onclick="getPage('myPage.php', 'content', 'GET', 'someAction: \"add\"');"
```

So what will a wise man do?

Comment: Well, for starters, a wise man wouldn't use `onclick` inline event handlers!

Comment: One option is: `data: dataStream,` and `onclick="getPage('myPage.php', 'content', 'GET', 'someAction=add');"`.

Comment: LOL @BenM I was about to write the same thing.

Comment: Sure I will use $('#someid').click(function() {
    // Do somthing
});

I'm still a newb, trying to figure things out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are mixing strings and objects.
In order to do what I think you want to do, you should call the function like this:

```
onclick="getPage('myPage.php', 'content', 'GET', { someAction: 'add' });"
```

i.e., you are passing an object as the fourth parameter, and not a string, then, in your function, you should treat that object as it is, i.e.

```
$.ajax({
  type: dataMethod,
  data: dataStream,
  url: '../' + targetURL,
  // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `dataStream` as a string, you shouldn't - it should be an object literal:

```
function getPage(targetURL, targetID, dataMethod, dataStream) {
  $.ajax({
    type: dataMethod,
    data:  dataStream ,
    url: '../' + targetURL,
    success:
        function(server_response)   { 
            $('#' + targetID).html(server_response).show();
        }
    });
  return false;
}
```

and then:

```
onclick="getPage('myPage.php', 'content', 'GET', {someAction: add});"
```

or

```
onclick="getPage('myPage.php', 'content', 'GET', {someAction: \"add\"});"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting an object, so give it one:

```
onclick="getPage('myPage.php', 'content', 'GET', {someAction: add});"
```

Then inside the function:

```
    data: dataStream,
```

without the braces